# Why is my Django SessionWizardView Survey Application Data not showing up in a usable format in my MySQL Database?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have built a multi-page survey application using a [Django 1.6.2 SessionWizardView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) but I am having some trouble with how the data submitted through the survey form is being saved in my MySQL database `django_db`. That is I simply do not recognize or understand what is being saved. This is my first time building an application like this or even working with a databases so please forgive my ignorance.

My problem is that when I look at my database via phpMyAdmin nothing is recognizable as being from my application, So I have no idea where to start.

I believe the data from my SessionWizardView should get stored in the `django_session` table but when I inspect it it looks like gibberish.

[image]

Here is a copy of the `session_data`- Is this what I am meant to be looking at?

```
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
```

## Questions:

1. Can someone take a look at my process/code below and tell me if I am
   missing a step, or have not included something in my code?
2. Am I missing something at the MySQL end? Should I be creating
   specific tables or somehow customizing it so that it stores the data
   in a useable/readable format?
3. Am I even looking in the right place for completed survey
   application data? Where does a SessionWizardView store/send it?

Once again this is my first database application so thank you for your patients

## Process:

- I created the database in MySQL (Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.20) via
  Terminal `CREATE database django_db;` and the tables in it are
  created when I run the command `python manage.py syncdb` Other than
  that I do not touch the database.
- I can complete my survey built using the SessionWizardView both on my
  local machine and on the public server. No errors and it apepars
  everything works fine
- I have setup phpMyAdmin and can see the `django_db` database. However
  I don't really know what I am looking at.

[image]

## Code:

**forms.py**

For the most part the survey has relatively simple questions such as:

```
class SurveyFormA(forms.Form):

#When were you born?
    birthdate = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(years = range(1995, 1900, -1)), label='What is your Date of Birth?', required = False)

#What is your current relationship status?   
    SINGLE = 'Single'
    INARELATIONSHIP = 'In a relationship'
    MARRIED = 'Married'
    DIVORCED = 'Divorced' 
    SEPARATED = 'Separated'
    WIDOWED = 'Widowed'

    RELATIONSHIP = (
        ("", "----------"),            
        (SINGLE, "Single"),
        (INARELATIONSHIP, "In a relationship"),
        (MARRIED, "Married"),
        (DIVORCED, "Divorced"),
        (SEPARATED, "Separated"),
        (WIDOWED, "Widowed"),
               )    
    relationship = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), choices=RELATIONSHIP, initial= "", label='What is your relationship status?', required = False)            

class SurveyFormB(forms.Form): #Internet usage questions

   (second page questions here)
   ....
   ....
```

These seem to work fine as you can see in the image below
[image]

Each of the SessionWizardViews has a `get_context_data` used for captureing and storing data from one page of the survey form to the next and `done` method. I am not showing the full `get_context_data` as it is quite long.

**views.py**

```
class SurveyWizardOne(SessionWizardView):                             
    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(SurveyWizardOne, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)  
        ....   
        ....                 

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        return render(self.request, 'Return_to_AMT.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],            
        })
```

## Database Connection:

My Django site is connected to a MySQL database in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': { 
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'django_db',                                       
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '************',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        #'PORT': '', 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you think anything is wrong. You haven't done anything to save any of your form results to the database, and in fact you haven't even created any models to save it in. The data you are looking at is a serialized dictionary that Django is using to keep the user's state between pages of the form.

Comment: Ok, well at least i know I am on the right path. So I am just missing the stage of saving the data to the Database. Have you any tips for this? Should the forms.py send it to the Database? and if so how? Or should I try get the data to models.py and add it to the Database that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either write the models.py or set a specific database that you have in mind to be the database accessed. Neither of which seem to be done here.

These links from the official documentation should help :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/databases/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/

PS - You should consider using Django 1.8 instead. It's even better documented and much easier to work with. Additionally porting your codes from one Django version to the next is really very easy. Hardly a little more than simple copy pasting.