# How to create a Person(models.Model): to store data submitted through a Survey Form?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have created a small Django (1.6.2) survey application split over multiple pages using a SessionWizardView connected to a MySQL database. [However I found out through this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108599/why-is-my-django-sessionwizardview-survey-application-data-not-showing-up-in-a-u)   that I had not created the necessary model to save the form data to the database.

What I am trying to do is create a separate entry in the Database for each person that completes the form. To do this I have tried to create a `Person(models.Model):` in `models.py` with corresponding entries to the survey questions in `forms.py`

When I run `python manage.py syncdb` I get no errors and I can see the newly created `survey_person` table through phpMyAdmin. When I check the table structure I can see each of the separate fields/rows representing the `Person(models.Model);` I just created.

The issue is that when I fill out and submit my survey application none of the data appears to be getting saved into the database.

**QUESTION: How do I get the data submitted through my survey form to be stored in the Database using the Person model I just created?**

If someone could show me even how to store one element e.g. `email` I am sure I can figure out the rest.

Thanks

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from survey.forms import SurveyFormA, SurveyFormB


class Person(models.Model):

    sender = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    birthdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    sex = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='Person_sex')
    smart_phone_ownership = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='Person_smart_phone_ownership')


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators
from django.forms import extras
import random

class SurveyFormA(forms.Form):

    sender = forms.EmailField(label='What is your email address?', required = False)

    birthdate = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(years = range(1995, 1900, -1)), label='What is your Date of Birth?', required = False)

    MALE = 'M'
    FEMALE = 'FM'

    SEX = (
        ("", "----------"), 
        (MALE, "Male"),
        (FEMALE, "Female"),
               )   
    sex = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), choices=SEX, initial= "", label='What sex are you?', required = False) 

class SurveyFormB(forms.Form): 

    YES_SMARTPHONE = 'Yes'
    NO_SMARTPHONE = 'No'

    SMART_PHONE_OWNERSHIP = (
        (YES_SMARTPHONE, 'Yes'),
        (NO_SMARTPHONE, 'No'),
               )    
    smart_phone_ownership = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=SMART_PHONE_OWNERSHIP, initial= "", label='Do you own a Smartphone?', required = False)

    ....
    ....
```

Any help is as always, much appreciated.

Comment: not sure about the declaration of your model, you set sex and smart_phone_ownership as foreign keys to person. Seems, looking at your forms, that they should be defined as `models.ChoiceField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `ModelForm` instead of a `Form`, your model should be saved automatically.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

from .models import Person


class SurveyFormA(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['sender', 'birthdate']

class SurveyFormB(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['smart_phone_ownership']
```

Your choices, help_text etc can be set directly in the model:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Person(models.Model):

    sender = models.EmailField(null=True)
    birthdate = models.DateField(null=True)

    MALE = 'M'
    FEMALE = 'F'
    SEX = (
        (MALE, "Male"),
        (FEMALE, "Female"))   
    sex = models.ChoiceField(choices=SEX, ...) 
    ...
```