# Django form data not submitting/visable in mysql database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I designed and built a Django 1.6.2 survey application using a SessionWizardView which is connected to a MySQL database.

The problem is that (as far as I can see) the submitted form data is not getting saved to the database. This is my first time building an application like this or even working with a database.

**Could someone take a look at what I have done and my code and point out any mistakes I have made as to why I cannot see any content submitted by my survey form?**

[The last time I posted a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108599/why-is-my-django-sessionwizardview-survey-application-data-not-showing-up-in-a-u) I was told I needed to create a Model for the data and it was suggested I use a `ModelForm` to create the table and columns in the database. I have done this but I am still not seeing my submitted content

## My Process

- I created the database in MySQL (Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.20) via
  Terminal `CREATE database django_db;` and the tables in it are created
  when I run the command `python manage.py syncdb`.
- I can complete my survey both on my local machine and on the public server. No errors and it appears everything works fine
- I have setup phpMyAdmin and can see the django_db database and `survey_person` model. However I can not seem to find any of the data that should be submitted by the form.
- I have tried to use the search facility in phpMyAdmin to find any of the form data I submitted but cannot see it
- I have exported the database as a .CSV file but it is empty.
- If I use the insert facility in phpMyAdmin the data gets saved in the DB and I can return it when I use the search facilities. The same data is also in the CSV file when I export it.

This seem to suggest that I am missing a step somewhere in my application when it comes to submitting content to the DB.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

## My Code

I have tried to limit the below to only relevant code

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': { 
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'django_db',                                       
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        #'PORT': '', 
    }
}
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^surveyone/$', SurveyWizardOne.as_view([
                                             SurveyFormA, 
                                             SurveyFormB,
                                             SurveyFormC,
                                             ....
                                             ....
                                             SurveyFormG,
                                             SurveyFormH,
                                             SurveyFormI
                                             ])),
```

**forms.py**

```
class SurveyFormA(forms.ModelForm):

    birthdate = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(years = range(1995, 1900, -1)), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['sender', 'birthdate', 'sex', 'relationship', 'state']



class SurveyFormB(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['internet_usage', 'smart_phone_ownership', 'smart_phone_usage']        

        widgets = {'internet_usage' : RadioSelectNotNull,
                   'smart_phone_ownership' : RadioSelectNotNull,
                   'smart_phone_usage' : RadioSelectNotNull,
                   }


class SurveyFormC(forms.ModelForm):   
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['education', 'wages', 'presentage_savings', 'occupation', 'living']        

        widgets = {'education' : forms.RadioSelect,
                   'wages' : forms.RadioSelect,
                   'presentage_savings' : forms.RadioSelect,
                   'occupation' : forms.RadioSelect,
                   'living' : forms.RadioSelect,} 

        ....
        ....
```

**models.py**

```
     sender = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='What is your email address?')     

        birthdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True) #overwritten in forms.py so passed no more arguments

        SEX = (
            ('MALE', 'Male'),
            ('FEMALE', 'Female'))    
        sex = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100, choices=SEX, verbose_name='What sex are you?')


        RELATIONSHIP = (
            ('SINGLE', "Single"),
            ('INARELATIONSHIP', "In a relationship"),
            ('MARRIED', "Married"),
            ('DIVORCED', "Divorced"),
            ('SEPARATED', "Separated"),
            ('WIDOWED', "Widowed"),)    
        relationship = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100, choices=RELATIONSHIP, verbose_name='What is your relationship status?')             



                ....

                ....

                def __unicode__(self):
                return self
```

**views.py**

My `views.py` are the most complex part of my application. Not sure if it necessary to show any but I thought just in case

```
class SurveyWizardOne(SessionWizardView):                             
    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(SurveyWizardOne, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)                      
        step = int(self.steps.current)        

        if step == 0:
            self.request.session['path_one_images'] = ['P1D1.jpg', 'P2D2.jpg', 'P3D3.jpg', 'P4D4.jpg', 'P5D5.jpg', 'P6D6.jpg', 'P7D7.jpg', 'P8D8.jpg', 'P9D9.jpg']    
            self.request.session['instruction_task_one_images'] = ['IT1A.jpg', 'IT1B.jpg', 'IT1C.jpg']    
            self.request.session['instruction_task_two_images'] = ['IT2A.jpg', 'IT2B.jpg', 'IT2C.jpg']    
            self.request.session['images'] = []
            self.request.session['slider_DV_values'] = []


        PATH_ONE_IMAGES = self.request.session.get('path_one_images', [])        
        images = self.request.session.get('images', [])
        slider_DV_values = self.request.session.get('slider_DV_values', [])
        INSTRUCTION_TASK_ONE_IMAGES = self.request.session.get('instruction_task_one_images', [])
        INSTRUCTION_TASK_TWO_IMAGES = self.request.session.get('instruction_task_two_images', [])

        if step in range (0, 27):   
            self.request.session['path_one_images'] = PATH_ONE_IMAGES                   
            self.request.session['images'] = images
            self.request.session['slider_DV_values'] = slider_DV_values
            self.request.session['instruction_task_one_images'] = INSTRUCTION_TASK_ONE_IMAGES
            self.request.session['instruction_task_two_images'] = INSTRUCTION_TASK_TWO_IMAGES

            if step == 0:
                instruction_task_first_image = random.choice(INSTRUCTION_TASK_ONE_IMAGES)     
                context['display_image'] = instruction_task_first_image                                 

            elif step == 1:
                instruction_task_second_image = random.choice(INSTRUCTION_TASK_TWO_IMAGES)   
                context['display_image'] = instruction_task_second_image  

            elif step == 9:
                first_image = random.choice(PATH_ONE_IMAGES)   
                PATH_ONE_IMAGES.remove(first_image)               
                context['display_image'] = first_image                                 
                images.insert(0, first_image)   
                self.request.session['first_image'] = images[0] 
                self.request.session.get('first_image')                          

            elif step == 10:
                second_image = random.choice(PATH_ONE_IMAGES)   
                PATH_ONE_IMAGES.remove(second_image)


            ....

            ....


        return context 


    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        return render(self.request, 'Return_to_AMT.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],            
        })
```

## phpMyAdmin

A screenshot of the DB from phpMyAdmin. NOTE: Not the hidden fields at the start are for introduction steps in the survey form, code not shown here for brevity.

[image]

Comment: So where's the bit that saves to the database, that is not working?

Comment: That is what I am confused by. I thought submitting the form would save the data to the database. What could be missing or broken?

Comment: I woud recommend you to start off with something simpler in order to understand it. Have you tried the Django tutorial? Also this will help you:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#the-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting data to a model form does not cause it to be saved automatically. If you want save data from a model form to the database, you need to call its [`save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) method. You could do this in the wizard's [`done()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.done) method.

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    # I don't know whether this will work, I am not familiar with your forms.
    for form in form_list:
        form.save()
    # Note the docs suggest redirecting instead of rendering a template.
    return render(self.request, 'Return_to_AMT.html', {
        'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],            
    })
```