# Correct <form action=" " URL for a SessionWizardView

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

[I have been having some trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334286/django-form-data-not-submitting-visable-in-mysql-database) getting a Django SessionWizardView to submit data to my database and I am trying to isolate the issue.

I note from the [Form documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#the-view)

> As well as its  elements, a form must specify two things:
>
> - where: the URL to which the data corresponding to the user’s input should be returned
> - how: the HTTP method the data should be returned by

and

> Form data sent back to a Django Web site is processed by a view,
>   generally the same view which published the form. This allows us to
>   reuse some of the same logic.

Currently I am using `<form action="/surveyone/" method="post">` which I believe is correct.

The issue is that my view is called `class SurveyWizardOne(SessionWizardView):` but if I try to use this in the `form action` I get an error as soon as I click Next on the first page of the survey.

**Question:** Based on the below is `action="/surveyone/"` correct?

Thanks

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^surveyone/$', SurveyWizardOne.as_view([
                                             SurveyFormIT1,
                                             SurveyFormIT2,
                                             Start,
                                             SurveyFormA, 
                                             SurveyFormB, 
                                             SurveyFormC, 
                                             SurveyFormD, 
                                             SurveyFormE,
                                             SurveyFormSpike1, 
                                             SurveyFormF1,
                                             SurveyFormF2,
                                             SurveyFormF3,
                                             SurveyFormDV1,
                                             SurveyFormF4,
                                             SurveyFormF5,
                                             SurveyFormF6,
                                             SurveyFormSpike2, 
                                             SurveyFormDV2,
                                             SurveyFormF7,
                                             SurveyFormF8,
                                             SurveyFormF9,
                                             SurveyFormDV3,
                                             SurveyFormDV4,
                                             SurveyFormDV5,
                                             SurveyFormG,
                                             SurveyFormH,
                                             SurveyFormI
                                             ])),
```

**views.py**

```
class SurveyWizardOne(SessionWizardView):                             
    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(SurveyWizardOne, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)                      
        step = int(self.steps.current)     



    ....
    ....


        return context 


    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        return render(self.request, 'Return_to_AMT.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],            
        })
```

**wizard_form.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block head %}
{{ wizard.form.media }}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}


<div class="main_content">   

<p>Page: {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>

<form action="/surveyone/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <table>   
                {{ wizard.management_form }}
                    {% if wizard.form.forms %}
                        {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
                        {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
                            {{ form }}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                        {{ wizard.form }}
                {% endif %}   
            </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your form is submitting to the same url, you can simply use `action=""`. If you prefer, you can use `action="/surveyone/"`

If you don't want to hardcode the url in your template, then you need to [name your url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns):

```
url(r'^surveyone/$', SurveyWizardOne.as_view([
                                             SurveyFormIT1,
                                             SurveyFormH,
                                             ...
                                             ]), name="survey_one"),
```

You can then use the [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tag in your template:

```
action="{% url 'survey_one' %}"
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming that I can simply use `action=""` I was using this previously but thought it might be causing the issue I highlighted in the other question. Nice tip on naming URL patterns too